# How to create an external unmanaged table in delta lake in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have this scenario where I am reading files from my blob storage and then creating a delta table in Azure Databricks. When you create a delta table in Datbaricks , there are delta files which are created by default which we cant access.

Other way is to create a unmanaged delta table and specify your own path to store these delta files. I would like to know how to do this. How can i specify where I want to store my delta files. and what does this external table mean, how can i specify the path for external table?
I tried below code and it fails on creating external table command:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.xyzstorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.xyzstorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.xyzstorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net", "<sas token>")



%sql
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS axytable
    LOCATION 'abfss://xyzstorageaccount/tables';
```

I know I might be doing something wrong here and I have not completely understood what external table actually means.. Does it stays inside the Databricks cluster and instead of providing my storage account path , should I provide Databricks path? How do i create a custom catalog which also seems to be a requirement here? Also this code works here and i am able to write it in storage account by the path provided but I fail to understand it.. Any SME who can help me out here?

```
path = "abfss://xxx@xyzstorageacount.dfs.core.windows.net/XYY"
(DF.writeStream
  .format('delta') 
  .outputMode("append") 
  .trigger(once=True) 
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .option('checkpointLocation', path+"/bronze_checkpoint")
  .start(path + "/myTable"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/lakehouse/data-objects.html#what-is-a-table) provide good description of what managed tables are and how are they different from unmanaged tables.  In nutshell, managed tables are created in a "default" location, and both data & table metadata a managed by Hive metastore or Unity Catalog, so when you drop a table, actual data is deleted as well.  Unmanaged tables are different as only metadata are controlled by Hive metastore or Unity Catalog - if you drop table, only table definition will be dropped, but not data.

You can create unamanged table different ways:

- Create from scratch using syntax `create table <name> (columns definition) using delta location 'path'` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html))
- Create table for existing data using syntax `create table name using delta location 'path'` (you don't need to provide columns definition)  ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html))
- Provide `path` option with path to data when saving table using `saveAsTable` (for batch), or `toTable` (streaming).  In your example it will be following:

```py
path = "abfss://xxx@xyzstorageacount.dfs.core.windows.net/XYY"
(DF.writeStream
  .format('delta') 
  .outputMode("append") 
  .trigger(once=True) 
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .option('checkpointLocation', path+"/bronze_checkpoint")
  .option('path', path + "/myTable")
  .toTable('<table_name>')
)
```

Comment: So I did what you mentioned, and created an unmanaged table(table name is audit2) as mentioned in step 3. When I navidate to my table in Databricks i.e. by clicking Data--> Database--><table_name> .. I get the error page saying "Schema:
An error occurred while fetching table: audit2
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
Sample Data:
An error occurred while fetching table: audit2"

Comment: I first copied all my json files into a Dtaframe and then created a database by below command and then ran the command to create unmanaged table. What wrong am I doing? "%sql
USE CATALOG hive_metastore;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS deltalake_db;
USE DATABASE deltalake_db;"

Comment: you need to use cluster configured correctly for access abfss...

Comment: What configuration to be specfic if you can provide that. I am having all rights to my storage account from where I am reading data and also storing the parquet format data. I am using the standard SKU Databricks workspace.

Comment: Can I create an external table in hive_metastore catalog as I am doing above or do i need to create another catalog for it?